# EntityIndexingInterceptor fails processing Hibernate proxy

Tags: hibernate-search

I have an EntityIndexingInterceptor that seems to throw a ClassCastException when confronted with a Hibernate Proxy object. Any suggestions?

The EntityInterceptor is placed on various subclasses within an inheritance tree.

```
    public class WallPostIndexingInterceptor implements EntityIndexingInterceptor<WallPost> {

        @Override
        public IndexingOverride onAdd(WallPost entity) {
            //Don't index status messages that are older than 60 days
            if(isEmpty(entity))
                return IndexingOverride.REMOVE;
            return IndexingOverride.APPLY_DEFAULT;
        }

        @Override
        public IndexingOverride onCollectionUpdate(WallPost entity) {
             return onUpdate(entity);       
        }

        @Override
        public IndexingOverride onDelete(WallPost entity) {
            return IndexingOverride.APPLY_DEFAULT;
        }

        @Override
        public IndexingOverride onUpdate(WallPost entity) {
            if(isEmpty(entity))
                return IndexingOverride.REMOVE;
            return IndexingOverride.UPDATE;
        }
```

Exception

```
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Error while indexing in Hibernate Search (before transaction completion); nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error while indexing in Hibernate Search (before transaction completion)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:218) ~[spring-orm-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-orm-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:592) ~[spring-orm-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:521) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy231.saveGroup(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        [...]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error while indexing in Hibernate Search (before transaction completion)
        at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.EventSourceTransactionContext$DelegateToSynchronizationOnBeforeTx.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(EventSourceTransactionContext.java:177) ~[hibernate-search-orm-5.3.0.Final.jar:5.3.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:722) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:391) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:516) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:584) ~[spring-orm-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        ... 145 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: nl.project.model.social.BaseWallPost_$$_jvsta00_5f cannot be cast to nl.project.model.social.WallPost
        at nl.project.dao.hibernate.search.interceptor.WallPostIndexingInterceptor.onUpdate(WallPostIndexingInterceptor.java:1) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.WorkPlan$PerClassWork.recurseContainedIn(WorkPlan.java:318) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.3.0.Final.jar:5.3.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.WorkPlan.recurseContainedIn(WorkPlan.java:143) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.3.0.Final.jar:5.3.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.processSingleContainedInInstance(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:296) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.3.0.Final.jar:5.3.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.appendContainedInWorkForInstance(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:231) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.3.0.Final.jar:5.3.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.appendContainedInWorkForInstance(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:171) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.3.0.Final.jar:5.3.0.Final]
```

Comment: Looks like the originating exception is caused in your own `WallPostIndexingInterceptor` ? This is possibly caused by having applied the interceptor on a wider type.

Comment: AFAIK it is caused by the proxy not being casteable to wallpost. The post in question is in fact a wallpost. But implementing the interceptor with basewallpost solves the issue. The application of the interceptor seems correct

Comment: In other words, it looks like a bug. But don't ask me to write a testcase on this one. ;-)